# Installing ojdbc8 jar file in IBM Liberty server

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, websphere-liberty

I am developing applications in Spring Boot and deploying in IBM Liberty server. Till now I have installed ojdbc8.jar in the local maven repository, included the dependency of ojdbc8.jar in pom.xml and packaged it inside a war file which is deployed in external IBM Liberty server. Now we need to externalize the ojdbc8.jar i.e. move it out of the war file, install it in IBM Liberty server and access it from there. Can anyone suggest me hoy to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html) page, and scroll to the Oracle section. It describes in detail how to set that up.

For Oracle

```
<dataSource id="DefaultDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/oracle">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
    <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/SAMPLEDB"/>
</dataSource>

<library id="OracleLib">
    <file name="C:/Oracle/lib/ojdbcx.jar"/>
</library>
```